# How to find and remove gems that are no longer used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle, gemfile

I working with medium Rails application which has about 60 gems dependencies. Many of these dependencies are unnecessary/useless.

Is there any way to find out which gems are not used by application?

Comment: Already found an answer?

Comment: @KeesSonnema, not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

You could however start with the following:

1) Go to http://rubygems.org/ and search for gems, you think aren't 'available' anymore. If they're removed from rubygems, You can't use them anymore so Delete them from your gemfile.

2) Just look carefully into your app and just write down which ones you're sure about. The ones you aren't sure about are the ones you don't use.

3) You can use this: http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/ to show the called parameters, call times, memory usage and object allocations

Hope it helps you :)